# UndoManager: redo to be performed 2x to restore 1 undo

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, undo-redo, nsundomanager

**Context**

A NSOutlineView with a NSTreeController bound to CoreData.

When a user deletes the last element of a group item in the outlineView, the group item is deleted automatically.
When the user uses undo() to undo the deletion, the group item is not expanded. To restore the expanded state I chose to use the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.NSUndoManagerDidUndoChange, object: nil, queue: nil, using: handleUndo) // Also works with NSTableView.textDidEndEditingNotification
}

func handleUndo(notification: Notification?) {
    self.managedObjectContext.undoManager?.beginUndoGrouping()
    self.managedObjectContext.undoManager?.disableUndoRegistration()
    self.restoreExpandedState() // Restore the expanded state on the group rows that need to
    self.managedObjectContext.undoManager?.enableUndoRegistration()
    self.managedObjectContext.undoManager?.endUndoGrouping()
}
```

The issue is that the user has to perform redo() twice after doing a single undo().
To be more concrete, the scenario is the following:

- user deletes a row in the NSOutlineView (doesn't matter if it is the last in the group)
- user wants to undo the delete and presses CTRL+Z (or via Edit > Undo)
- user wants to redo the delete : **he has to hit SHIFT+CTRL+Z (or via Edit > Redo) twice**

How comes? If thought disabling the undo registration would do the trick but it doesn't.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Not saying this is the cause, but viewWillAppear can be called multiple times - maybe you're adding multiple observers?

Comment: I checked and unfortunately, this is not the case. But thanks anyway for the idea :-).

Comment: Is your code intended to "patch" the `restoreExpandedState` function into any undo operation?